# Count the vowels that are found between two consonats C++

Tags: c++, string

So I've tried to solve this, an algorithm which counts and prints the number of vowels which are found between two consonats in a string. 
I've made a program but it keeps giving me the wrong answers and I really don't know what could be wrong.
For example, for input: *"oasele sunt fragile"* it should print 4 but it actually prints 5.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    char s[255];
    int isvoc(int i)
    {
        char c=tolower(s[i]);
        if (isspace(c)) return 0;
        else
            if ((c=='a') || (c=='e') || (c=='i') || (c=='o') || (c=='u')) return 1;
                else return 0;
    }
   int main()
   {
   cin.get(s,255);
   int l=strlen(s),nr=0;
    for (int i=1;i<l-1;i++)
        if (!(isvoc(i-1)) && (isvoc(i)) && !(isvoc(i+1))) nr++;
   cout<<nr;
   }
```

Comment: Could you please include the wrong answers you are getting?

Comment: Just added, sorry.

Comment: You are not Welsh  y is a vowel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: just a side note: it's also worth taking a look at the STL algorithms library; in production code you'd want to leverage STL for stuff like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting vowels that appear between non-vowels.  So in "a e i" you will get a count of 1, not 0.  You would need:

```
if (iscon(i-1) && isvoc(i) && iscon(i+1))
```

Where you can implement iscon() any number of ways, such as

```
bool iscon(int i) { return isalpha(str[i]) && !isvoc(i); }
```

Comment: FYI... it is clear that you are a beginner, maybe a student?  I suggest studying other code.  There is a lot, I mean tons and tons, out there in the wild.  Someone with more experience would not use a global array to hold a string, at least if they were trying to write code that is usable in several contexts.  At the least you would be passing around char or char*, not indexes into the array, and most likely you would be using std::string instead of char arrays.